# execution time of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix, execution-time

What is the age old method of testing execution time of stored procedures on informix 11.5. I am thinking of doing something like this from a unix prompt:

```
$ time (echo 'execute procedure foo(1)' | dbaccess ...)
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: To get the proposed syntax to work, you'd need to use: `time sh -c "echo 'execute procedure foo(1)' | dbaccess"`.  As shown, you would get a syntax error from the shell.  As noted by RET, you can simply time dbaccess: `echo 'execute procedure foo(1)' | time dbaccess ...`.  But I'd still use (my) SQLCMD program.

Comment: Also notice that your timing will include the time of starting DB-Access, and establishing the database connection; SQLCMD allows you to separate these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do something more elaborate, but if that's all you need, why bother? Obviously if there are more steps, move the sql into a separate file and run

```
time dbaccess <dbname> file.sql
```

btw, there's a quote missing from your code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I use my SQLCMD program for this sort of job.  It has a benchmark mode (-B option), and also makes it easier to write the SQL:

```
sqlcmd -d stores -B -e 'execute procedure foo(1)'
```

It is open source and available from the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software/).